# Is there such a thing as an MSP432 launchpad guide for absolute beginners?

Tags: embedded, launchpad

I've done so much research both on this site and on Google and Youtube, yet haven't been successful at finding any good resources to learn how to develop for this launchpad with code composer.

Most tutorials either teach you to work with Energia or are aimed towards professional users. I just started working with this launchpad as part of my engineering training and I already feel left behind, so I'd appreciate it if someone points me to some good resources that assume no background.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are some nice free MOOCs focusing on TI MCUs.

Comment: Most microcontroller tutorials assume knowledge of C, so you should learn the basics if that first.

Comment: This [Embedded Systems Programming course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Ii-GyLCwaE&list=PLfcIZXsDLA1-QEyrD4R9YcWWKpbCcrGVP) does not use your exact board and tool chain but it's a good introduction.

Comment: read the fine manuals http://dev.ti.com/tirex/#/?link=Software%2FSimpleLink%20MSP432E4%20SDK%2FDocuments%2FQuick%20Start%20Guide

Comment: @CL I meant prerequisites in embedded. Particularly working with registers and such. I'm actually very familar with C, and we've had fields in electronics so I'm also familiar with combinatorial and sequential circuits, just not how they're being used in this launchpad and microcontrollers in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are lucky enough that it's 2017 right now so there are plenty of resources. I will name just a few that I'm aware of:

1. General [MSP430 LaunchPad Workshop](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Getting_Started_with_the_MSP430_LaunchPad_Workshop). This is the resource I used when first started playing with MSP430 launchpads and it's indeed a good starting point for the beginners. It is based on CCS and supports many MSP430 launchpads including MSP432.
2. [TI SimpleLink MSP432 academy](http://www.ti.com/microcontrollers/simplelink-mcus/simplelink-academy.html). This would be a good choice for the next step as it covers more specific and advanced things such as multithreading, Wi-Fi and Bluetooth communication, and the like. It's also based on CCS.
3. [Video training series](https://training.ti.com/msp432%E2%84%A2-low-power-high-performance-mcus-training-series) can be used as an overview of MSP432 architecture and internal modules/peripherals.
4. As mentioned in the comments already, there are some free online courses available for MSP432. I personally participated in the edX course [Real-time Bluetooth Networks - Shape The World](http://edx-org-utaustinx.s3.amazonaws.com/UT601x/RTOS.html) (great course btw). The downsides are that this course is a little bit advanced for the beginners and also uses Keil as IDE

Answer (score 2):

TI provided the MSPWare code examples which go from a simple led blink to more complex options.

They also have a wiki with plenty of examples, including an entire course online.

http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Getting_Started_with_the_MSP430_LaunchPad_Workshop

Then there is other guides like this one from the University of texas.

http://users.ece.utexas.edu/~valvano/arm/downloadmsp432.html